# Tinymce обрезает "-"

Tags: php, tinymce

столкнулся с такой проблемой, TinyMCE начинает обрезать символы &nbsp, -, /, и прочие.
Что мне делать? Невероятно раздражает.

Answer (score 0):

Я сам решил проблему, это было связано с типом кодирования символов, добавьте этот параметр

```
entity_encoding : "raw"
```

И все починится.